# How can I change the landing page after a success Laravel login?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

I am absolutly new in **Laravel** and I have the following problem. I am using **Laravel 5.3**.

When I perform the login from my login page it automatically land me on this **home** page:

```
http://localhost:8000/home
```

My doubt is: how can I change the landing page after a success login?

I have these routes:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Betrivius/WorkSpace/betriviusExtranet (master)
$ php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name     | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |          | App\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController@index                    | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |          | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | POST     | doLogin                |          | App\Http\Controllers\LoginBetriviusController@doLogin                  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   |          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
|        | POST     | login                  |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
|        | POST     | password/email         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | password/reset         |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
|        | POST     | register               |          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
+--------+----------+------------------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

So I tried to modify my **LoginController** (related to the **App\Http\Controllers\Auth** namespace) changing this value from:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

to:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard-hotel';
```

where **dashboard-hotel** represents the **dashboard-hotel.php** view that I want to open just after a success login.

But doing in this way I obtain the following error message:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 766
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 621
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('C:\Users\Andrea\Documents\Betrivius\WorkSpace\betriviusExtranet\public\index.php') in server.php line 21
```

This is my **/routes/web.php** file content:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'LoginBetriviusController@index');

Route::post('/doLogin', 'LoginBetriviusController@doLogin');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

So, what is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `Route::get('/dashboard-hotel', 'DashboardHotelController@index');` to your **/routes/web.php**
2. Create a file in **app/Http/Controllers** named **DashboardHotelController.php**
3. Put this content there

> ```
> <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> class DashboardHotelController extends Controller
> {
>   /**
>    * Create a new controller instance.
>    * DashboardHotelController constructor.
>    */
>   public function __construct() {
>       $this->middleware('auth');
>   }
>
>   /**
>    * Show the application dashboard.
>    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
>    */
>   public function index() {
>
>       return view('dashboard-hotel');
>   }
> }
> ```

4. Create a file in your **resources/views** folder named **dashboard-hotel.blade.php**
5. Write there your HTML/Blade code
6. Do not forget to open terminal and type `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: mmmm can you give me more information? /dashboard-hotel is the requested resouce and YourLandingPageController@itsMethod represent the controller and themethod that render a specific view? So this method should return my view?

Comment: What exactly does "composer dump-autoload -o" statment?

Comment: It is updating autoloader indexes to use your new DashboardHotelController class, you need to do it only when adding a new class, or changing/removing existing.

Comment: I thought the `composer dump-autoload` has more to do with the composer installed vendor packages, and to update the Laravel app specific files you would want to run `php artisan optimize`, but I could be wrong there. On another note, if you are caching your route file `php artisan route:cache`, and are running into issues with your new route not appearing in `php artisan route:list` you will need to run `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: to update composer installed packages you need to do `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload -o` doing the same as `php artisan optimize`, btw you can add it to your **composer.json** file, into "scripts" -> "post-update-cmd" section to be called automatically after `composer update`